# Laravel show undefined index:year even the field is hidden by jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, laravel

In a registration form I have a select category which allows you to hide or show the inputs according to type to select in select category. this form is to choose whether you're a faculty or student, when you choose student the hidden input fields(year input field & section input field) will display. When I choose faculty and I click on button register, validation system check other value even it is hidden by jQuery, then it stops the registration how solved this problem.

**Registration blade**

```html
<form class="px-3" method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                                @csrf

                                <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus placeholder="Name">

                                                            @error('name')
                                                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                                                </span>
                                                            @enderror

                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <input id="mobile" type="mobile" class="form-control @error('mobile') is-invalid @enderror" name="mobile" value="{{ old('mobile') }}" required autocomplete="mobile" placeholder="Phone Number">

                                                            @error('mobile')
                                                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                                                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                                            </span>
                                                            @enderror
                                </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" placeholder="Email">

                                                            @error('email')
                                                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                                                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                                            </span>
                                                            @enderror
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                     <input id="password" type="password" class=" form-control @error('password')
                                     is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="password" data-toggle="password" placeholder="Password">
                                                            
                                    @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @enderror

                                </div>

                                 <div class="form-group">
                                    <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control @error('password-confirm')
                                     is-invalid @enderror" name="password_confirmation"
                                    required autocomplete="new-password" placeholder="Confirm Password" data-toggle="password"  >
                                    
                                    @error('password-confirm')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @enderror

                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                     <select class="form-control @error('category')
                                     is-invalid @enderror" name="category" id="category" required>
                                    <option selected disabled>Register As:</option>
                                    <option value="faculty">Faculty</option>
                                    <option value="student">Student</option>
                                    </select>

                                    @error('category')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @enderror

                                </div>

                            <div class="form-row hidden form-input" id="pDetails">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <select class=" input form-control @error('uyear') is-invalid @enderror" name="uyear" id="uyear" >
                                        <option selected disabled>Year</option>
                                        <option value="First year">First Year</option>
                                        <option value="Second Year">Second Year</option>
                                        <option value="Third Year">Third Year</option>
                                        <option value="Fourth Year">Fourth Year</option>
                            </select>

                            @error('uyear')
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                            </span>
                            @enderror

                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <input id="usec" type="text" class=" input form-control @error('usec')
                            is-invalid @enderror" name="usec" placeholder="Section" >

                            @error('usec')
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                            </span>
                            @enderror

                            </div>

                            </div>
                               <!-- <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox small">
                                                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck">
                                                <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck">Remember
                                                    Me</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>-->


                                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block">
                                            Register
                                        </button>
                                        <hr>

                                </form>
```

**Jquery**

```js
<script>
        $('#category').change(function(){
            var responseID = $(this).val();
            if(responseID =="student"){
                $('#pDetails').removeClass("hidden");
                $('#pDetails').addClass("show");
            } else{
                $('#pDetails').removeClass("show");
                $('#pDetails').addClass("hidden");
            }
            console.log(responseID);
        });
</script>
```

**Registration Controller**

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');

    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
            'mobile' => ['required' ,'string' ,'unique:users'],
            'category' => ['required' ,'string'],
            'uyear' => ['nullable' ,'string'],
            'usec' => ['nullable' ,'string'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\Models\User
     */


    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $user = config('roles.models.defaultUser')::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'category' => $data['category'],
        'mobile' => $data['mobile'],
        'uyear' => $data['uyear'],
        'usec' => $data['usec'],
        ]);

        $role = config('roles.models.role')::where('name', '=', 'User')->first();  //choose the default role upon user creation.
        $user->attachRole($role);

        return $user;

    }

    public function registered(Request $request, $user){

        // $user

    }
}
```

Comment: While hiding elements disable them using jquery as well.  Then they will not be submitted.  Whereas hidden fields will be submitted anyways.  You can even give hidden fields default values instead of disabling them.  Then there should be no error.

Comment: How can i do that? Can u help me?

Answer (score 0):

Change your jquery function to disable the form element while hiding it and enable the same while showing it.

```
  <script>
    $('#category').change(function(){
        var responseID = $(this).val();
        if(responseID =="student"){
            $('#pDetails').removeClass("hidden");
            $('#pDetails').addClass("show");
            $( "#uyear" ).prop( "disabled", false );
        } else{
            $('#pDetails').removeClass("show");
            $('#pDetails').addClass("hidden");
            $( "#uyear" ).prop( "disabled", true );
        }
        console.log(responseID);
    });
```

Instead of disabling the form element, you can give a default value like this.

```
  <script>
    $('#category').change(function(){
        var responseID = $(this).val();
        if(responseID =="student"){
            $('#pDetails').removeClass("hidden");
            $('#pDetails').addClass("show");
            $('#uyear').val("");
        } else{
            $('#pDetails').removeClass("show");
            $('#pDetails').addClass("hidden");
            $('#uyear').val("faculty");
        }
        console.log(responseID);
    });
```

Comment: It doesnt work, the output is "Undefined index: uyear"

Comment: When I chose faculty in the select category it always give me "Undefined index:uyear" while if I chose student it works well.

Comment: Maybe you can give default value to that column in database.

Comment: How can I do that? Can u help me? Because im just a student.

Comment: Now it doesnt give me the undefined index error, but when I click the register button it just load and the data doesnt go to the users table.